# CheckAccess. Agile Web Application Development with Yii1.1

Tags: yii

I need some help with CheckAccess function. 
I'm reading book *Agile Web Application Development with Yii1.1 and PHP5*, and came to **page 212**. On this page I've to added a "Create user" menu item. 
I login with the user that is associated with the project (in Db table project_user_role) like a member, and members has operateion called '*createUser*'.

The problem is that I can't see the menu item which should be generated by the following code:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('createUser', array('project' => $model))) {     
    $this->menu[] = array('label' => 'Add User To Project', 'url' => array('adduser', 'id' => $model->id));  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, this book is great, but I remember it had some small errors in it. I'm going to see if I still have my TrackStar project and try and help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I think mistake is in my db, cause I have a table AuthAssignment with 0 rows...

Answer (score 1):

Also with AuthAssignment there are two more tables and even having them is not full deal. You got to have set RBAC :).

Please See[Role-Based Access Control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control)